# Обработка появления PopupMenu нажатой ячейки

Tags: c++, c++builder

Морской бой.

Ручное расставление кораблей. Есть динамический созданный массив контролов `TCell` (ячейки поля) унаследованных от `TGraphicControl`. Для каждого контрола задается `PopupMenu`, в котором есть список доступных кораблей для расставления. У каждой ячейки есть методы `GetX()` и `GetY()`, которые получают местоположение на поле по горизонтали и вертикали соответственно. По нажатию идет проверка можно ли поставить в данную ячейку корабль с заданными параметрами и в случае успеха ставит корабль, удаляет пункт меню.

[image: PopupMenu]

Как реализовать обработчик, который будет получать значения X и Y ячейки `TCell`, которая отобразила этот `PopupMenu`? Если ещё проще: как получить ссылку на тот компонент, который отобразил `PopupMenu`?

Comment: В событии OnPopup пытался сохранить ссылку на TObject для дальнейшего приведения его к типу TCell, но не выходит. Некорректная ссылка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У PopupMenu есть свойство PopupComponent в котором хранится ссылка на объект, который отобразил меню.